# Is there a way to visualize the properties of $\rm CO_2$ regarding IR to a layman?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, atmospheric-science, infrared-radiation, climate-science

I think about how to explain the greenhouse effect to somebody with no physics background. What to explain to a general layperson, basically.

I have ideas how to go on from that CO₂ are some kind of particle, and they get warm when hit by a heat particle.

The step before is to explain that there are two kinds of gases, normal gases, and greenhouse gases. The first are transparent for heat, the greenhouse gasses are not.

But because there are no obvious examples for the difference in the visible spectrum, I feel that this is just a statement that does not explain it. I know well enough what the difference actually is, but that is not helpful for a minimal explanation for a layperson.

I'm looking for - ideally - a way to explain that step.
In the absence of that, it could be helpful to practically show the difference in a demonstration experiment.

It should just convince a naive observer that there are two kinds of gas, one can get warm in the sun, the other can not.

An approach that is not directly suitable for the demonstration would be:

- preparing two confined volumes of gas, pressurized as a balloon, or not pressurized as a bag of very light material.
- filling one with CO₂, and the other with dry air
- irradiating both at the same time with strong IR, for example created by an incandescent halogen light.

The light could be inside or outside the gas container. If inside, there would be strong convection and heat transport by mass flow - so that's not a good option. Maybe convection could be avoided by heating with a strong flashlight instead of continuous lighting? Maybe part of the unpressurized container could use reflective coating?

Would that, if done in a scale fitting into a common living room<sup>*</sup>, class room or Olympic stadium, possibly show any effects that are not only measurable, but comprehensible for a layperson?
How could the effect demonstrate the point that needs to be explained?

I'd be interested to hear whether this approach makes sense and is worth refining, but also alternative approaches for the demonstration, even as vague concepts

---

*<sub>This use of the term living room as a value representing an order of magnitude requires that volumes of typical living rooms are consistent within one order of magnitude. I think that may be true it living room is defined as a separate room allocated for the function.</sub>

Comment: What is your objective?

Comment: @DavidWhite To create a minimal explanation for how the greenhouse effect works in terms of changes in balances of temperatures and radiation levels of surface and atmosphere. For the start, I need to establish that greenhouse gasses exist, but also others. As I have no way to explain it in the abstract, I look for a way to somehow demonstrate it in a convincing way.

Comment: Greenhouse gasses don't absorb energy from sunlight. The ground absorbs the energy, and then the ground re-radiates the heat at _much longer wavelengths_ that _are_ absorbed by the greenhouse gasses. You won't prove anything just by shining light from a halogen bulb through a box of gas.

Comment: One can see CO2 with an IR camera: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O1fJ3UuSFaU

Comment: What about using liquids to get the same effect across but more compactly/visually?

Comment: @VolkerSiegel, the general public tends to be scientifically illiterate and a heat balance for the earth is somewhat complicated.  Note that water vapor is the most important greenhouse gas, so attributing most or all greenhouse warming to CO2 is scientifically duplicitous.

Comment: @DavidWhite That's the part where I know what I want to explain, so that is not an issue. For example, water vapor can be included by generalizing greenhouse gases. (There is some positive feedback of CO2 increase to total greenhouse gas level including water, of course) The thing is about not using heat balances in the abstract. For example: Looking from the outside to the earth, you get heat that is balanced with what the earth receives from the sun. Because if earth would radiate more heat than it gets from sun, it would cool down, and radiate less. That stays constant with climate change.